# Write a Script for K Means based on Constraint

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, geospatial, k-means

**How to Apply Constraint based K Means Clustering on GeoSpatial Data?**
I am trying to write a program for k means with constraint on Geospatial Data in python.
I have a Geospatial Data point with their locations coordinates pair of longitude and latitude and constraint column quantity. I want to find number of CLUSTER. so in each Cluster data point must be near about with respect to their locations and they won't interfere in any other Clusters such as point of A Cluster won't be available in between of other Cluster points such if we create a polygon for A Cluster from their data points, polygon A (Cluster A) won't be intersect with other Clusters(other territories) and for each Cluster summation of quantity column should be in between of 15000 to 18000.

I am attaching the snapshot of first 38 datapoints of GeoDataFrame and point from QGIS
[Points on QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lseNX.png)
[first 38 Data points from a GeoDatframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6q9l.png)

I want to create number of number of Cluster with respect to all conditions: like I am attaching the points and drawn polygons using snipping tools, I am so bad in drawing so please excuse in my drawing.

[Polygons/Territories with points, without interfering any points from others territory points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqRL1.png)

I tried using K Means Clustering writing my script, and later on shift points, in which territory value is less than lower limit (15000) but value is exceeding by upper limit.

```
n_territories = number_of_cluster(geodataframe=gdf, col_name=col_name, threshold_value=threshold_value)

if num_of_cluster is not None: 
    if num_of_cluster >n_territories:n_territories= int(num_of_cluster)
    #n_territories = int(num_of_cluster)
    # if n_territories<4: n_territories= 4
# else: n_territories = int(gdf[col_name].sum()/threshold_value)-2
# if n_territories > (int(gdf[col_name].sum()/threshold_value)-2): n_territories = int(gdf[col_name].sum()/threshold_value)-2  
# Generate 2000 unique random hex color codes with high contrast
# n_territories = int(gdf[col_name].sum()/threshold_value)


threshold_value1= threshold_value*1.2
#unique_high_contrast_color_codes = [random_high_contrast_color(used_color_codes) for _ in range(n_territories)]
unique_high_contrast_color_codes = generate_unique_complementary_colors(n_territories)
coordinates = np.array(gdf.geometry.apply(lambda geom: (geom.x, geom.y)).tolist())
gdf_array = gdf[['ttpl_id',col_name,'geometry']].values
points = gdf_array[:, 2]
first_point = min(points, key=lambda point: (point.x, point.y))
gdf_array = sorted(gdf_array, key=lambda row:  first_point.distance(row[2]))
gdf_array = np.vstack(gdf_array)
#Initializing the centroid 
centroids = kmeans_plusplus_init(coordinates,n_territories, see=see)
# Find the assignments of data points to centroids
assignments = assign_to_nearest_centroid(gdf_array, centroids)
gdf_array = np.column_stack((gdf_array,np.full(len(gdf_array), '0')))
# Create an array of values corresponding to the assignments
values = np.concatenate([np.full(len(assignment), i) for i, assignment in enumerate(assignments[0])])
# Assign the values to the appropriate positions in gdf_array
gdf_array[np.concatenate(assignments[0]), 3] = values
categories = np.unique(gdf_array[:, 3]) ###finding the unique cluster id (3rd Column) from each points 
sum_per_category = [np.sum(gdf_array[gdf_array[:, 3] == cat][:, 1].astype(int)) for cat in categories]  # Calculate the sum of the cluster id (unique value 3rd Column) for each category
result = np.column_stack((categories, sum_per_category)) # Combine the category labels and the sums into a new array
dist_val, sum_constraint = calculate_sse(gdf_array, centroids, threshold_value)
dist_old= 1
sum_constraint_old= 1
dist_tol= abs(dist_val-dist_old)/dist_old
const_tol= abs(sum_constraint-sum_constraint_old)/sum_constraint_old
result1= result[result[:,-1]<threshold_value]
result2= result[result[:,-1]>threshold_value]
it_= 0
while (dist_tol> 0.0001 or const_tol>0.0001) and it_<20:
    arr1 = np.empty_like(gdf_array[:1,:])
    for item in result2:
        id_ = item[0]
        gdf_array = gdf_array[np.unique(gdf_array[:, 0], return_index=True)[1]]
        gdf_array = sorted(gdf_array, key=lambda row:  first_point.distance(row[2]))
        gdf_array = np.vstack(gdf_array)
        gdf1_array1= gdf_array[gdf_array[:,3]==id_]
        points = gdf1_array1[:, 2]
        median_point = Point(np.median([point.x for point in points]), np.median([point.y for point in points]))
        distances = np.array([round(haversine_distance(row[2], centroids[id_]),2) for row in gdf1_array1])
        gdf1_array1 = np.column_stack((gdf1_array1, distances))
        gdf1_array1 = gdf1_array1[np.argsort(gdf1_array1[:, -1])]
        cumulative_sum = np.cumsum(gdf1_array1[:, 1])
        gdf1_array2 = gdf1_array1[:np.argmax(cumulative_sum > threshold_value1),:]
        gdf3_array = gdf1_array1[np.isin(gdf1_array1[:, 0], gdf1_array2[:,0], invert=True)]
        gdf1_array1 = gdf1_array1[np.isin(gdf1_array1[:, 0], gdf1_array2[:,0], invert=False)]
        if np.sum(gdf1_array2[:, 1])>=threshold_value1:
            centroids[id_] = MultiPoint(gdf1_array1[:,2]).centroid
    for item in result1:
        try:
            id_ = item[0]
            cluster_sum = item[-1]
            gdf_array = gdf_array[np.unique(gdf_array[:, 0], return_index=True)[1]]
            gdf_array1= gdf_array
            distances = np.array([round(haversine_distance(row[2], centroids[id_]),2) for row in gdf_array1])
            gdf_array1 = np.column_stack((gdf_array1, distances))
            gdf_array1 = gdf_array1[np.argsort(gdf_array1[:, -1])]
            #gdf_array1 = np.vstack(sorted(gdf_array1,key=lambda row:  centroids[id_].distance(row[2]) ))
            cumulative_sum = np.cumsum(gdf_array1[:, 1])
            gdf_array2 = gdf_array1[:np.argmax(cumulative_sum > (threshold_value1)),:]
            gdf_array2[:, 3] = id_
            gdf_array2= np.concatenate((gdf_array2[:,:-1], gdf_array[gdf_array[:,3]==id_]), axis=0)
            gdf_array = gdf_array[np.isin(gdf_array[:, 0], gdf_array2[:,0], invert=True)]
            arr1 = np.concatenate((arr1, gdf_array2), axis=0)
        except:pass
    gdf_array = np.concatenate((arr1[1:, :], gdf_array), axis=0)
    # Extract the first column
    gdf_array = gdf_array[np.unique(gdf_array[:, 0], return_index=True)[1]]
    centroids = np.empty((n_territories,), dtype=object)
    for j in range(0, n_territories):
        centroids[j] = MultiPoint(gdf_array[gdf_array[:,3]==j][:,2]).centroid
    ############condition checking:
    sum_per_category = [np.sum(gdf_array[gdf_array[:, 3] == cat][:, 1].astype(int)) for cat in categories]
    # Combine the category labels and the sums into a new array
    result = np.column_stack((result, sum_per_category))
    result1= result[result[:,-1]<threshold_value]
    result2= result[result[:,-1]>threshold_value]
    dist_old= dist_val
    sum_constraint_old= sum_constraint
    dist_val, sum_constraint = calculate_sse(gdf_array, centroids, threshold_value)
    dist_tol= abs(dist_val-dist_old)/dist_old
    const_tol= abs(sum_constraint-sum_constraint_old)/sum_constraint_old
    it_= it_+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure there isn't a way to do this without having to create a weird work-around that undermines the point of ML.

There are a few algorithms that you can specify cluster sizes, though as far as I can tell, these can all produce non-convex clusters. This makes it incredibly difficult/impossible to create non-overlapping geomatries around the clusters.

I think you need to take more time to consider what you are doing and why.

1. Why do you have a cluster size requirement?
2. What happens if you have a number of points that can't be clustered completely. E.g., if you have 37,000 points, then you are either going to have 1-7,000 points left over, or more than 2 clusters but each with fewer than 15,000 points.

If you want to use mathematical clustering techniques, you shouldn't change their output because you want something else. You need to design your experiment better to suit your task.